# JDBC not registering metrics on spring boot 2 when @RefreshScope is on DataSource Bean

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

I have an application that uses spring boot 2 and logs metrics from micrometer. I want to log jdbc (mysql) min, max, and active connections periodically. I also want to use @RefreshScope on my datasource bean to prevent hikari binding exceptions when injecting configs on the fly from spring admin. I find that when I use @RefreshScope on config class/datasource bean JDBC does not register itself with the MeterRegistry.

Is it possible to have JDBC register itself with the MeterRegistry with @RefreshScope?

Is there a way to progammatically register JDBC with the MeterRegistry in my bean definition?

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@RefreshScope
public class DbConfig {

@Primary
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Removing @RefreshScope allows JDBC to automatically register with the MeterRegistry but causes the below exception on config change:
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Could not bind properties to 'HikariDataSource' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource' to javax.sql.DataSource

Answer (score 2):

Add `javax.sql.DataSource` as an extra refreshable. `application.yml` file example:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    refresh.extra-refreshable:
      - javax.sql.DataSource
```

and remove @RefreshScope from your class.
Other solution would be cast the DataSource to HikariDataSource.
I use the first solution because of DataSource creation is done by external library in my application.

Reference: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/318